# Finding the unknown cardinality of a Set given other information

Tags: combinatorics

How would you go about finding the number of elements in $A$ if you know that the number of elements in $A\cup B$ is $20$, the number of elements in $B$ is $7$ and the number of elements in $A\cap B$ is $3$?

I did it this way: I let $x$ be the number of elements in $A$. So
                   $x+7-3=20$ implies that
                   $x+4=20$ and so
                   $x=16$.
Does anyone agree with me or is there a different way to solve this?

Comment: @A Glenn : drawing a Venn diagram helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's the correct answer. More generally, by an inclusion-exclusion argument, $$|A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B| \implies 20 = |A| + 7 - 3 \implies |A| = 16$$